# How to wrap the logic inside a react useMemo using react and typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I want to wrap the logic inside react usememo using typescript and react.

What am I trying to do?

I have an object "filter" and within that there is `availableItems` which is an array of strings. I want to check if there is two strings "type1" and "type2" within `availableItems`.

I have a select menu which should be disabled if `availableItems` is not empty array and `availableItems` has either type1 or type2

below is the code,

```
let isSelectDisabled;
if (filter && filter.availableItems) {
    const hasTypes = (filter.availableItems.some((el: any) =>
      ['Type1', 'Type2'].includes(el))
    );
    isSelectDisabled = filter.availableItems.length >= 0 && !hasTypes;
}

return (
    <label>SelectItems</label>
    <Select
        disabled={isSelectDisabled}
    />
);
```

Could someone help me how to wrap above logic in `useMemo`?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this as a solution. Dependencies may vary according to your requirements

```
const isSelectDisabled = useMemo(() => {
    if (filter && filter.availableItems) {
        const hasTypes = (filter.availableItems.some((el: any) =>
          ['Type1', 'Type2'].includes(el))
        );
        return filter.availableItems.length >= 0 && !hasTypes;
    }
}, [filter])
```

Answer (score 1):

Pass a function that returns the desired value, and an array of state variables the function depends on to `useMemo`.

```
const isSelectDisabled = useMemo(() => {
    if (!filter?.availableItems?.length) return false;
    return !filter.availableItems.some(el => ['Type1', 'Type2'].includes(el));
}, [filter]);

return (
    <label>SelectItems
        <Select disabled={isSelectDisabled} />
    </label>
);
```